# How to set up SMTP server on Windows 7

Tags: windows, email, smtp

This sounds dumb, but how do you set up an SMTP server in Windows 7 (not Windows Server)? After researching on Google, all I get are either tutorials on how to set up your inbox in an email client or how to set up an SMTP server using Windows Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 doesn't include SMTP service so you need to install [Remote Server Administration Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887).

After that you should be able to find [configuration instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), like SMTP in IIS.

Comment: This is not true. This will allow you to manage other servers - but Windows 7 is not a server OS, so you can't use it to manage the machine you've installed it on (see: http://serverfault.com/a/361081)