# C# SMTP mail sending

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I wish to send an email by C# console application. I found source codes - which are mostly look alike.But my problem I think, I dont know the how- to of this issue.

- I think, there should be a smtp server which installed somewhere. I have given an server ip address and told its an exchange server. So I tried to use it as server address in source code.
- I used the given cridentals related to this server. But each time I got "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay Error"..
- Then I tried [How to set up SMTP server on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988054/how-to-set-up-smtp-server-on-windows-7) this but I think for a client installing smtp layer is not necessary..

So, how can I overcome this problem ?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

That´s exactly what I do to send emails. Here the code (you have to replace **port**, **Server** and **enablessl** with the correct values)

```
    public static void SendMail(string addressTo, string addressFrom, string mailSubject, string mailBody)
    {
        NetworkCredential myCredential = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _passWord);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "99.99.127.233";
        client.Port = 417;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = myCredential;
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(addressFrom);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(addressTo);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = mailBody;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = mailSubject;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Send(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with smtp.gmail.com. I enabled **"Access for less secure apps"** and turned off 2-step verification. It worked.

try this code

```
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com");
                message.Subject = "Subject";
                string body = "Mail Body";
                message.Body = body;
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                NetworkCredential networkCredentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "<password>");
                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = networkCredentials;
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a similar thing at the moment, just in a Windows Form. I use the library EASendMail (https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail). It has various classes such as a standard Mail class that you can use like this:

```
void SmtpSend(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        // \/ Use
        EASendMail.SmtpMail testMail = new EASendMail.SmtpMail("test");
        testMail.From = from;
        testMail.To = to;
        testMail.Subject = subject;
        testMail.TextBody = body;
        // Alternatively, you can use HTML bodies with testMail.HtmlBody = "<html><head></head><body></body>" etc. 
        // Just play around with it.
        // \/ Use the SmtpClient class to send your SmtpMail objects \/
        EASendMail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username", "password");
        smtpClient.SendMail(testMail);
    }

    void main()
    {
        SmtpSend("sender@yourapp.com", "reciever@yourapp.com", "Test Mail", "Test Body");
    }
```

You can also use the `SmtpServer` object if your want to connect to a server directly:

```
            SmtpServer smtpgm = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");
            EASendMail.SmtpClient cln = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();
            smtpgm.Port = 587;
            smtpgm.User = Console.ReadLine();
            smtpgm.Password = Console.ReadLine();
            smtpgm.Alias = "W";
            smtpgm.Protocol = ServerProtocol.SMTP;               
            smtpgm.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSTARTTLS;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this message is being sent to **postfix**, hosted by yourself (or someone you can get assistance from), make sure to enable the `login` SASL authentication scheme.  By default, usually only `plain` is enabled.
Otherwise your requests will be treated as *anonymous* (regardless of your credential settings on `SmtpClient`), and the remaining of the configuration will likely cause your request to be blocked.

TL;DR

Troubleshooting can be done on the postfix machine, by enabling verbose debugging in your postfix configuration. 
This can be done usually /etc/postfix/main.cf, by adding this line: (with `81.82.83.84` being the (public) IP-address of the machine running your SmtpClient code)

```
debug_peer_list = 81.82.83.84
```

Than let your `SmtpClient` make a new request, while investigating your logging (usually in `/var/log/mail.info`).
A successful session will show an incoming (`<`) `AUTH login` request, resulting in a successful reply (`Authentication successful`)

```
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-smtpserver.smtpdomain.com
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-PIPELINING
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-SIZE 20480000
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-VRFY
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-ETRN
# Postfix tells SmtpClient that it can use AUTH "LOGIN" scheme
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250-8BITMIME
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 250 DSN
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: watchdog_pat: 0x55c423dbbdd0
# AUTH request
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: < unknown[81.82.83.84]: AUTH login b3JnYW5pbW1vQGZveGlubm9xxx
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: query milter states for other event
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: milter8_other_event: milter inet:localhost:8891
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: xsasl_dovecot_server_first: sasl_method login, init_response b3JnYW5pbW1vQGZveGlubm9xxx
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: CONT?1?UGFzc3dv
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 334 UGFzc3dv
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: < unknown[81.82.83.84]: QXplcnR5MDE=
# AUTH reply
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: xsasl_dovecot_handle_reply: auth reply: OK?1?user=authenticationuser
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: > unknown[81.82.83.84]: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: watchdog_pat: 0x55c423dbbdd0
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: < unknown[81.82.83.84]: MAIL FROM:<user@destinationdomain.com>
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: extract_addr: input: <user@destinationdomain.com>
Jul 10 08:04:20 smtpserver postfix/submission/smtpd[13312]: smtpd_check_addr: addr=user@destinationdomain.com
```

Without enabling the `login` authentication scheme, the `250-AUTH` response will only contain `PLAIN`, and the `SmtpClient` will not authenticate.
As said, this will likely cause your message to be blocked by helo, client, relay, sender or recipient restrictions.

If your postfix uses dovecot for SASL authentication, enabling the `login` SASL authentication scheme can be done in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf`:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login cram-md5
```

(And make sure only one such configuration exists in your configuration files.)
More information can be found here: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms  (where it is shown to also enable `cram-md5` beside `plain` and `login`)

If your message still gets blocked further on, you can add `permit_sasl_authenticated` as the first restriction of the postfix restriction settings - at least temporarily - for further investigation.
e.g. (in my case I chose to put it after `permit_mynetwork` to allow sending mails from local host)

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain,permit
#...
```