# Error loading in ASP.NET Email verification URL at localhost

Tags: asp.net, email

I am using smtp gmail to for email verification. It is assigned as per the standards. When a new user registers, it is able to send mail to user along with URL for verification. But on clicking the URL which the user receives, it is unable to load the page. What might be the error

the URl address is like 
string url = "http://localhost:49432/EmailVerification.aspx?vcode=" + id

this is what my smtp class mail looks like

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"];
     smtp.Port = 587; // 465; //Gmail works on this port
    //  smtp.Port = 25;  
    smtp.Timeout = 100000;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FROMEMAIL"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FROMPWD"]);
    smtp.Send(objmail);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MSG", "alert('Mail Sent Sucessfully');", true);
```

in the webconfig file. I have given

Comment: This has nothing to do with SMPT since you said the email was successfully sent!.. you should debug your page "Email Verification" to see what's happening.

Comment: Hello Moe, I tried to debug using visual studio, there was no error. when I try to view in browser. It is unable to load.

Comment: Try hosting ur site in IIS instead of IIS express.

Comment: Already I tried it everything is working fine except email verification URL is not loading even with IIS. I hosted it in IIS 7

Comment: What's the URL for the email verification?

Comment: https://localhost:49432/Emailverification.aspx

Comment: Are u kidding me lol? thats the IIS express link..

Comment: May be funny I am new to asp.net, when I run through visual studio IIS express is activated. I deployed the website to IIS 7. Now, I am confused what is going. Totally confused

Comment: Now I got one thing, using port number like above mentioned URL is through IIS express and with virtual directory it is IIS. Is that right. So may be I am using IIS express port and I deployed the same in IIS. this might be cause for my error. If this correct please let me know, how to do it.

Comment: It is loading when I browse through IIS express, when I run using google chrome. But, when I browse website deployed to IIS, then it shows the error. In windows 7 we don't have smtpserver. I downloaded some windows pack by referring to website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988054/how-to-set-up-smtp-server-on-windows-7

Comment: If you hosted your site to your IIS just open it directly in your browser or using browse from your IIS. Attach the process to debug your issue

Comment: Hi Moe, thanks I am able to browse my website and other page through browser directly without help of visual studio.